# Возможно ли с помощью наследования создать в классе обьект родительского класса?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Возможно ли с помощью наследования создать в классе обьект родительского класса и если да,то как к нему можно обратиться?

Код:

```
class Plane//родитель
{
public:
    Plane()=default;
    ~Plane() = default;
    std::string getNumber() const { return number; }
    std::string getBrand()const { return brand; }
    std::string getReleaseDate()const { return releaseDate; }
    double getCarrying()const { return carrying; }
    size_t getPassengersCount()const { return passengersCount; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Plane&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Plane&);
    void changeItem();
private:
    std::string number;
    std::string brand;
    std::string releaseDate;
    int carrying;
    int passengersCount;
    
};
class Pilot//родитель
{
public:
    Pilot() = default;
    ~Pilot() = default;
    std::string getSurname()const { return surname; }
    size_t getworkExperienceYears() const { return workExperienceYears; }
    std::string getAddress()const { return address; }
    std::string getDateOfBirth()const { return DateOfBirth; }
    double getSalary()const { return salary; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Pilot&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Pilot&);
     void changeItem();
private:
    std::string surname;
    size_t workExperienceYears;
    std::string address;
    std::string DateOfBirth;
    double salary;
};
```

В классе наследнике были созданы 2 поля, куда я раньше просто присваивал объект класса, но хочу реализовать это с помощью наследования:

```
class Flight :Pilot,Plane
{
public:
    Flight() = default;
    ~Flight() = default;
    void setPilotandPlane(Pilot& pi, Plane& pl) { static_cast<Pilot&>( this), plane = pl; pilotSurname = pi.getSurname(), planeNumber = pl.getNumber(), planeBrand = pl.getBrand(), cargoWeight = pl.getCarrying(); }
    void changeItem();
    std::string getflightNumber()const { return flightNumber; }
    std::string getFinishDate()const { return finishDate; }
    std::string getStartDate() const { return startDate; }
    std::string getPilotSurname()const { return pilotSurname; }
    std::string getPlaneNumber()const { return planeNumber; }
    std::string getPlaneBrand() const { return planeBrand; }
    double getKm()const { return km; }
    double getCost()const { return cost; }
    std::string getStartPoint()const { return startPoint; }
    std::string getFinishPoint() const { return finishPoint; }
    size_t getCountOfStops() const { return countOfStops; }
    size_t getCountOfSoldTickets() const { return countOfSoldTickets; }
    size_t getCargoWeight() const { return cargoWeight; }
    Pilot& getPilot() { return pilot; };
    Plane& getPlane() { return plane; };
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Flight& flight);
    friend  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Flight& flight);
protected:
    /*Pilot pilot;
    Plane plane;*/
    std::string flightNumber;
    std::string finishDate;
    std::string startDate;
    std::string pilotSurname;
    std::string planeNumber;
    std::string planeBrand;
    double km;
    double cost;
    std::string startPoint;
    std::string finishPoint;
    size_t countOfStops;
    size_t countOfSoldTickets;
    size_t cargoWeight;
};
```

Comment: Добавьте Ваш код с классами и на его примере поясните, что хотите сделать. Пока не особо понятно, как здесь "поможет" наследование.

Comment: При наследовании в классе **всегда** создается объект родительского класса.

Comment: @V-Mor исправил

Comment: @user7860670 а как к нему обратиться в наследнике?

Comment: так же, как и к самому классу

Comment: @user7860670 this.родитель?

Comment: нет, просто this.parent_field

Comment: @user7860670 я хочу присвоить обекту класса наследника объект класс родителя,код есть ниже ,мне для этого нужно перегрузить = и обращаться к полям get и set`aми ,просто я думал ,что класс наследник состоит из нескольких обектов ,но наверное копируются просто поля и методы ,я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Для этого ничего перегружать не надо, можно написать `child = parent` и оно вызовет `parent::operator =`

Comment: я не могу в родителе this=child,мне нужно так

Comment: вот это поворот... `this = child` не будет работать так как this - это указатель на объект, а не сам объект или ссылка на него. Чтобы присвоить его сначала надо разыменовать `*this`, далее *" я хочу присвоить обекту класса наследника объект класс родителя"* - Это наоборот - `*this = parent` внутри класса потомка

Comment: @user7860670 да,ошибся ,но даже если сделать разименование то компилятор не позволит так сделать без перегруженного оператора =

Comment: ну тогда `static_cast<parent &>(*this) = p;` или `parent::operator =(p);`

Comment: @user7860670  спасбо большое за ответ

Comment: @Vanya Неужели для вашего вопроса понадобилось столько кода? Думаю нет, и вынужден воздержаться от положитжльного голоса за ваш вопрос. Если поправите вопрос, то дайте знать комментаарием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно создать. Обратиться вот так вот:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x = 42;
};

struct B : A {
    A a;
} b;

int main() {
    std::cout << b.a.x << '\n';
}
```

Обращение к члену базового класса без создания экзмепляра базового класса:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x = 42;
};

struct B : A {
} b;

int main() {
    std::cout << b.A::x << '\n';
}
```

Лучше для ваших целей использовать агрерирование, как и было. [Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704455/13970074)

Comment: так мы создаем объект 2 раза ,а возможно ли к нему обратиться только по наследованию ,ведь по идее наследник уже должен содержать объект базового класса

Comment: @Vanya обновил ответ

Comment: если я правильно понял, то я могу написать так: this->Pilot=Pilot pi

Comment: @Vanya не знаю, что за `Pilot`, я же показал, как обращаться

Comment: мне нужно обратиться не к полю класса родителя,а к самому родителю в классе наследнике.Это вообще возможно?

Comment: @Vanya приведите минимальный пример того, что вы хотите. Непонятно, зачем вам это надо

Comment: в моем классе flight было 2 переменные типа Plane ,Pilot ,все было хорошо и удобно,я подумал что я могу заменить это переменные с помощью наследования ,но когда мне понадобилось переменной flight присвоить новый plane в одном из методов ,стал вопрос а как и возможно ли вообще обратиться в наследнике к родителю,я скорее всего не понимаю как устроенно наследование,я думал что наследник содержит обекты родителей,а наверное при наследовании копируются просто поля и методы

Comment: @Vanya кажется понял. Родитель разрушается после наследника, поэтому присвоить ему другое значение не получится. Если у вас никак не связаны наследники и родители использовать наследование, тем более с несколькими базовыми классами, не надо, агрегирование (переменные, как у вас и было) лучше. Вот [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704455/13970074)

Comment: Fligh это this ,Pilot pi  (Pilot&)*this = pi работает!

Comment: @Vanya ну далее в ответе сказано, что так лучше не делать

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то как-то вот так, например:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A // Базовый класс
{
    int x = 5;

public:

    int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
};

class B : A // Наследник
{
public:

    A makeSomeA()
    {
        return A(); // Создаёт в классе B объект родительского класса B
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;

    A a = b.makeSomeA(); // Обращается (получает) созданный объект

    std::cout << a.getX() << std::endl;

    getchar();
    
}
```

P.S. Значение элемента `x`, как и весь прочий "лишний" код сделан для демонстрации того, что объекты действительно созданы и работают, как и следует работать обычным объектам классов.